# linq datetime not contain max or min

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq

I am getting this error that the datetime does not contain max or min method. I am trying to get the meeting max and min date and see if they are equal and then set MeetingDate to the min datetime. If they are not equal then I will concat both min StartDate and max StartDate together. below is what the output should look like and the error I am getting is datetime not contain max or min method.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<MeetingModel> Meeting = new List<MeetingModel>();

            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 1, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 18) });
            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 1, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 19) });
            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 2, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 22) });
            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 2, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 22) });
            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 3, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 23) });
            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 3, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 23) });
            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 4, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 25) });
            Meeting.Add(new MeetingModel() { MeetingId = 4, startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 29) });


            var result =  Meeting
                          .Select (p=> new MeetingViewModel
                          {
                             MeetingId = p.MeetingId,
                             MeetingDate = p.startTime.Max() == p.startTime.Min() ? p.startTime.Min().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") :
                                        string.Format("{0: MM/dd/yyyy} - {1: MM/dd/yyyy}", p.startTime.Min(), p.startTime.Max()
                          }).ToList();

            foreach (var meeting in result)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("{0}", meeting.MeetingId);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", meeting.MeetingDate);
            }
        }


        class MeetingModel
        {
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public DateTime startTime { get; set; }        
        }

        class MeetingViewModel
        {
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public string MeetingDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   CS1929  'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Max' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'

[image]

Output

```
Meeting 1 2017/1/18 - 2017/1/19
Meeting 2 2017/1/22
Meeting 3 2017/1/23
Meeting 4 2017/1/25 - 2017/1/29
```

EF

```
select new Model.Meeting
                       {
                           MeetingId = m.MeetingId,
                           GroupId = m.GroupId,
                           MeetingDate = m.Min(x => x.startTime) == m.Max(x => x.startTime) ?
                                         m.Max(x => x.startTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") :
                                        string.Format("{0: MM/dd/yyyy} - {1: MM/dd/yyyy}", 
                                        md.Min(x => x.startTime), md.Max(x => x.startTime))
                       }).GroupBy(x => x.MeetingId).ToList();
```

Comment: put your cursor over Max or Min, then press Ctrl+Spacebar and see if any of the suggestions work for your problem

Comment: If I'm a search engine or visually impaired, I can't read the error message. Please include error messages as text, not only as pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by `MeetingId` and use `.Min` and `.Max` linq methods to fetch dates :

```
var result = Meeting
    .GroupBy(x => x.MeetingId)
    .Select(p => new MeetingViewModel
    {
        MeetingId = p.Key,
        MeetingDate = p.Min(x => x.startTime) == p.Max(x => x.startTime) ?
            p.Max(x => x.startTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") :
            string.Format("{0: MM/dd/yyyy} - {1: MM/dd/yyyy}", p.Min(x => x.startTime), p.Max(x => x.startTime))
    }).ToList();
```

Test in dotnetfiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/IJaehf

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: would I also be able to use this in entity-framework? I updated with the EF logic

Comment: @Jefferson will be work too, in the query posted for EF, you should group by before use `Min` and `Max` because are applied in the enumerable, [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)

Answer (score 1):

Please try `DateTime.MinValue` or `SqlDateTime.MinValue`.
These are implemented as `static readonly` fields and not methods.

Comment: where should I add that in the select?